# Using the definiton of the t-distibution prove that t-statistic has t-distirbution

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, statistical-inference

I am trying to prove that t-statistic has a t-distribution, but I am pretty much lost at the moment. I was not able to find any proofs in the internet as well. Can somebody help me to understand how to prove it?

Comment: To be honest, knowing the level of the class that I am participating in I highly doubt that this is want my teacher meant. I think that by the definition of t-distribution he meant the formula for t-distribtion  which is used in hypothesis testing rather than for density function.  Is it possible to prove that using this particular formula?

Comment: It can be a really simple proof

Comment: See the second answer.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. That looks perfect. Thank you :)